# jQuery: selecting href attr and displaying in html input, TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="popup">plain old text</div>

<div class="popup_link"><a href="http://link.com">cool link</a></div>
```

I have the following jQuery:

```
function show_value( foo ) {
  var value = $('<div class="popup_box">');
  var input = $('<input>');
  input.val(foo.text());
  value.append(input);
  $('body').append(value);
  input.select();
  return value;
}

var init = function(){
  var value;

  $('div.popup').hover(function(){
    value = show_value( $(this) );
  }, function(){
    value.remove();
  }
}
```

Right now, when you hover over "plain old text", you will see an input with "plain old text" as its value:

```
<input value="plain old text" />
```

What I want to do next is have the same effect, except with the value of the attribute href.
So: when you hover over the link "cool link", you will see an input with "http://link.com" as its value.

```
<input value="http://link.com" />
```

So far I've fiddled with this in jquery (new portion added to the bottom):

```
var init = function(){
  var value;

  $('div.popup').hover(function(){
    value = show_value( $(this) );
  }, function(){
    value.remove();
  }

  var link_value;

  $('div.popup_link').hover(function(){
    link_value = show_value( $(this).find('a').attr('href') );
    // alert( $(this).find('a').attr('href') ); //testing, shows "http://link.com" properly
  }, function(){
    link_value.remove();
  }
}
```

As you can see, the alert works fine.
However, the show_value function gives an error: "TypeError: foo.text is not a function"

Can someone show me where I went wrong, and what I need to change?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use `string` as `DOM object`

```
input.val(foo.text());
```

you're applying the `text()` method to string, cause

```
$(this).find('a').attr('href')
```

returns string, but not the `DOM object`
So you need to change your `show_value()` function to smth else like

```
function show_value( foo ) {
  var value = $('<div class="popup_box">');
  var input = $('<input>');
  input.val(foo);
  value.append(input);
  $('body').append(value);
  input.select();
  return value;
}
$('div.popup_link').hover(function(){
    link_value = show_link_value( $(this).find('a').attr('href') );
 }, function(){
     link_value.remove();
}) //btw here you've missed the bracket
```

**UPD** Added fiddle.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mhqqpff/1/)

Comment: Worked perfectly!  However, now the link_value.remove()  portion is no longer working (the input persists). Is there something I need to change there too?

Comment: @Jay Updated answer. Fiddle works fine for me. If you see smth else   show me some fiddle and i'll tell more.

Comment: Nevermind! It was a misplaced parenthesis on my part. Works like a charm now, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`show_value` is currently taking a jQuery object as its parameter, but `$(this).find('a').attr('href')` is not a jQuery object in your call to `$('div.popup_link').hover`. That's why you're receiving that error. You can change the meaning of the parameter to be a value instead:

```
function show_value( foo ) {
  var value = $('<div class="popup_box">');
  var input = $('<input>');
  input.val(foo);
  value.append(input);
  $('body').append(value);
  input.select();
  return value;
}
```

and then your call to `$('div.popup').hover` should change as follows:

```
$('div.popup').hover(function(){
  value = show_value( $(this).text() );
}, function(){
  value.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to treat the `foo` parameter as a jQuery object by placing inside a `$()`, as in `$(foo)`. But once you fix that, you're also going to run into an error with the section of code where you set `link_value`. You're trying to call jQuery functions on a plain string, so what you'll want to do instead is just get rid of the `attr()` call and instead have something like this:

```
$('div.popup_link').hover(function(){
    link_value = show_value( $(this).find('a') );
}, function(){
    link_value.remove();
});
```